# How to create a customized report for each Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a multiple Amazon EC2 instances and I need to make a report for the Cost & Usage of each of them.

I tried the regular report and it is useless. Does someone know the steps to  create a customised report?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to build your own.

You can now access your AWS billing data programmatically.

To get started, all you need to do is to provide an Amazon S3 bucket for your billing data, give the AWS Billing system permission to write to it, and visit the Billing Preferences page to enable programmatic access:

Once you have done this, AWS will generate an Estimated bill several times per day and store it in the bucket, where you can download and process it as desired. AWS will also generate a Final bill at the conclusion of each billing period.

Billing Reports are generated as CSV files and include plenty of details:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/detailed-billing-reports.html

Comment: I think that you don't understood my questions clearly , what i want to do is create a report for each EC2 instance and i do not have any S3 bucket in the console .

Comment: In order to create a custom report, you need the data. So AWS will push the data into one S3 bucket which you have to create. This bucket name needs to be provided in the billing dashboard. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-programmatic-access-to-aws-billing-data/